# OrderConfirmationController.php page under prestashop can execute custom module

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want add a table when front end order confirmation is done and same way when admin also can order for customer . so, is there any system in prestashop fire trigger when any order placed then module can execute or directly can put on orderconfirmation controller or adminordercontroller

Please let me know if it is possible.

example- i have made a module & want add a record into new table when OrderConfirmationController.php  run or order confirmed.  same way in admin order confirmed then.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways through which you can track the order creation and editing. It will totally depends on your need. I am describing below some hooks that are related to order management.

1. **actionObjectOrderAddBefore**
   You can use this hook if you want to validate new order before saving into database.
2. **actionObjectOrderAddAfter**
   This hook will be executed after saving new order in database. You can use this hook to fullfill your need.
3. **actionObjectOrderUpdateBefore**
   This hook will be called just before updating existing order. But I am not recommend this hook to use because this hook will be called every time whenever any field of existing order is update.
4. **actionObjectOrderUpdateAfter**
   This hook will be called just after updating any field of order into database. Do not use this hook, if you want to create entries in custom table for corresponding order.
5. **actionValidateOrder**
   This hook will be executed whenever the customer places new order. You can use this hook if have no dependencies on payment success because this hook execute after creating order but not guarantee that customer will pay the amount for order or not.
6. **orderConfirmation**
   This is the optimal and recommendable hook to track the order detail after placing order by customers. This hook is called after creating order into database as well as payment success.

For more information or any query reply me.

Comment: Sorry to add. I am looking for a solution. Can I just enquire what is the trigger for actionValidateOrder? I am facing an issue whereby it is not working for PayPal module only, other payment gateways are fine.....

Comment: Can you please share you code snippet about what you are trying?

Comment: Yes, I have a made a post with regards..... I have sent my orders to a delivery vendor by API. It is only working for other payment options and not for PayPal only. I am using actionValidateOrder.

Comment: Please cross check in your paypal module that, this module is triggering hook that you are using to detect orders.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `actionValidateOrder` hook in the custom module that you have created. This hook is called every time an order has been generated.

Use following code to register the hook (inside install() function)

```
$this->registerHook('actionValidateOrder');
```

And then defined the function for the hook as follows, it will be called whenever a new order has been generated:

```
public function hookActionValidateOrder($params)
{
     --- YOUR CODE HERE ---
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hook actionValidateOrder or override the PaymentModule::validateOrder, or even override the Order::add. It depends at what point you want to do and what data you need.
Do need the order completed? Do you need to save or change something before the order is completed? And you can use the parent function before or after what you need to do.